# select word of 3 letter with a regex

Tags: java, regex

I search a way to detect all word who have more then 3 letters.

For word of 6 to 12 character, i think we can do:

```
(?=\w{6,12}\b)
```

Is there a way to do 4 to infinite?

Answer (score 4):

You can do unbounded captures with a minimum. Use the following regex:

```
(?=\w{4,}\b)
```

If, for whatever reason, the library does not support that capability, you can also fall back to good ol' plus:

```
(?=\w\w\w\w+\b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
(\b\w{4,}\b)
```

i.e. replace `{6,12}` with `{4,}`.  The `{4,}` means "4 or more."  In Java, you would escape the backslashes to write this as

```
"(\\b\\w{4,}\\b)"
```

Comment: i tried with this string:This is a string that. Nothing matches... why?

Comment: @roberttrudel I slightly modified my answer to include the way to express this regex in Java with escaped backslashes.  Also, I removed the zero lookahead specification on the group (that is, I dropped the ?=), which doesn't really make sense for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{}` with no second number to specify no upper bound.

```
/(?=\w{4,}\b)/
```